# Select UNIQUE return

Tags: mysql

I have a table as following:

```
id   | vid | data | time
------------------------------------
1    |  4  |  0   | 1333635317
2    |  4  |  1   | 1333635323
3    |  2  |  0   | 1333635336
4    |  4  |  1   | 1333635343
5    |  5  |  0   | 1333635349
6    |  5  |  1   | 1333635350
```

I want to be just a row (the last row [ID: 4,6]) of the same rows`[id:1,2,4,5]`, how it will output the query?

I mean, as a result of these:

```
id   | vid | data | time
------------------------------------
3    |  2  |  0   | 1333635336
4    |  4  |  1   | 1333635343
6    |  5  |  1   | 1333635350
```

What do i do?

i trying it as:

```
SELECT * from tbale as t1 where vid = 4 GROUP BY vid ORDER BY id DESC
```

but doesn't work ORDER BY in my query.

Comment: You're actually `GROUPing by vid`: How do you choose which row to return? Do you always want the one with max(time) and the corresponding id, max(id) and the corresponding time, or just any id and any time, as far as it appeared together with this `vid`?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 2):

Select the MAX(time) grouping by vid and find the corresponding Id.

```
select t1.id, t1.vid, t1.data, t1.time
from yourTable t1
     join (select vid, max(time) as time
           from yourTable
           group by vid) t2
     on t1.vid = t2.vid
     and t1.time = t2.time;
```

If you need WHERE or ORDER BY:

```
select t1.id, t1.vid, t1.data, t1.time
from yourTable t1
     join (select vid, max(time) as time
           from yourTable
           group by vid) t2
     on t1.vid = t2.vid
     and t1.time = t2.time
WHERE t1.SOME_FIELD = SOME_VALUE
ORDER BY t1.SOME_FIELD;
```

Comment: how is it with `select *`?

Comment: Give this error: `Unknown column 't2.time' in 'on clause'

`

Comment: ok,tnx. how can add `where` and `order by` in this query?

Comment: where with a variable and order by id `DESC`

Comment: why does it need DESC, is there any ORDER BY @Mehdi?

Comment: ORDER BY DESC: To display in the table.Newer first row.

Comment: There is a MAX() condition, it doesn't need order by desc. @Mehdi

Comment: @Mehdi if you are the same user that posted the question, please **[merge your accounts.](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)**

Answer (score 1):

try this

`select t1.* from tb5 t1 inner join` 
`(select max(time) as ti,vid from tb5 group by vid order by time desc) t2` 
`on t1.vid = t2.vid and t1.time = t2.ti;`

check here [on fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9bab6/1)